# Can't use facebook's quick replies

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to use facebook's quick replies - 
at first I tried to use IMessageActivity's SuggestedActions property

```
IMessageActivity result = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
result.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
result.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
result.SuggestedActions = suggestedActions.Select(x => new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = x,
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = x
                }).ToList()
```

but, as it didn't work for facebook, I found another solution based on ChanelData

```
result.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new {
                quick_replies = suggestedActions.Actions.Select(x => new
                {
                    content_type = "text",
                    title = x.Title,
                    payload = x.Value is null ? x.Title : x.Value
                }).ToArray()
            });
```

sadly it still doesn't work. Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a TextPrompt with the PromptOptions like this:

```
await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = new Activity
    {
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Text = "¡Bien! Ahora te envié un código de acceso a tu teléfono. Por favor ingrésalo aquí cuando lo recibas.",
        SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = "Reenviar token", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Reenviar token" }
            },
        },
    }
});
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you dont want to use prompts, try this:

```
Activity activity = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
activity.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
activity.Text = "This is an example of SuggestedAction";
activity.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
{
    Actions = new List<CardAction>()
    {
    new CardAction() { Title = "Action", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Action" }
    }
};
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity);
return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution.
I'm not sure I want to implement dialogs in my app (it is more of a proxy), is there any way to use this prompt message with ITurnContext and IMessageActivity?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you can use HeroCards and attach them to an activity and send that via SendActivityAsync.

```
Activity activity = _context.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
        var buttonList = new List<CardAction>();

        foreach (var prompt in Prompts)
        {
            buttonList.Add(
                new CardAction { Value = prompt.DisplayText, Type = "imBack", Title = prompt.DisplayText, });
        }

        var heroCard = new HeroCard { Text = "message text", Subtitle = string.Empty, Buttons = buttonList };

        activity.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This is similar to how a qnaMaker chat bot sends prompts through to registered channels